# Getting the sum and pick the max key value pair with out parallelize in spark scala

Tags: scala

I have a Seq(String) as below and I need to reduce by key

```
val sq = Seq("a:5", "b:6", "c:10", "a:12", "c:8", "b:11")
```

I don't want to use parallelize as I have to do it for each record in the dataset.I need the result as below, the sum of the keys and I pick the maximum key value.

```
result: Seq("c:18")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you need to use spark?

Comment: no just the scala ,which has better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sq.map{ str =>
  val Array(k, v) = str.split(":")
  (k, v.toInt)
}.groupBy(_._1).map{ case (k, kvs) =>
  (k, kvs.map(_._2).sum)
}.maxBy(_._2)
```

1. Parse the strings into `(String, Int)` pairs (first `map`)
2. Group by the string (`groupBy`)
3. Sum the values in each group (second `map`)
4. Find the one with max value (`maxBy`)